# Как преобразовать строку "2 + 2" в операцию?

Tags: java, алгоритм

Собственно вопрос, как строку "2+2" преобразовать так что бы на выходе получить целочисленное значение 4 (не конкатенация)

Comment: Это называется evaluation. См. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/how-to-evaluate-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605032/is-there-an-eval-function-in-java/2605051 и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

Это известная задача и есть для нее решение.

Можно написать ручками - https://craftinginterpreters.com/parsing-expressions.html

А можно взять что то готовое для java - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432245/how-to-parse-a-mathematical-expression-given-as-a-string-and-return-a-number

Comment: о, и сюда минусаторы подъехали

Comment: сразу говорю это не я )

Comment: Из русскоязычного я бы посоветовал http://algolist.ru/syntax/parsear.php `Алгоритм Бауэра и Замельзона` достаточно легко реализуется. С другой стороны - какой смысл велосипедить, если есть вагон готовых решений...

Comment: или хороший вариант для старта - [алгоритм сортировочной станции](https://www.pvsm.ru/java/3665)